# I reinstalled ubuntu and now I don't see my RAID drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, mdadm

I originally had a Ubuntu 12.04 system with RAID5 array that I built using mdadm.

Due to issues with graphics drivers, the 12.04 system crashed and I had to reinstall the operating system. After various install / reinstall attempts (and attempt to try and use boot-repair from a livecd). I finally got my system back up running Ubuntu-Gnome 14.04. But now my raid is gone.

I'm afraid something happened when I used boot-repair. I kept getting messages saying: Raid Detected you should install mdadm (at which point I did), and then it asked about some other md program and said I should remove that because it caused issues with mdadm or something. Also during the ordeal gparted yelled at me several times about a corrupt GUUID Partition Table on one of the drives.

I can verify with gparted that the 3 drives I used to make my RAID5 are still there and are still formatted with the ext4 filesystem.

For the three disks the output of

```
sudo sgdisk -p /dev/sdb
sudo sgdisk -p /dev/sdd
sudo sgdisk -p /dev/sde
```

is

```
mycomputer:/dev$ sudo sgdisk -p /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 3907029168 sectors, 1.8 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): D3E28B01-CBD8-40EB-B421-4BA0BEF275D9
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 3907029134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2157 sectors (1.1 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048      3907028991   1.8 TiB     8300  R1b


mycomputer:/dev$ sudo sgdisk -p /dev/sdd
Disk /dev/sdd: 3907029168 sectors, 1.8 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 21E3C879-F658-47E1-AB34-D1EA25EC6FFC
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 3907029134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2157 sectors (1.1 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048      3907028991   1.8 TiB     8300  R2d


mycomputer:/dev$ sudo sgdisk -p /dev/sde
Disk /dev/sde: 3907029168 sectors, 1.8 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 48CFD331-24FC-4D30-B8A2-EFFA709B9600
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 3907029134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2157 sectors (1.1 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048      3907028991   1.8 TiB     8300  R3e
```

so it looks like the drives are still in tact and have all the data that was originally there.  I have a script where I recorded all of the commands I used to create the array, but I am very unsure / nervous about how to rebuild and mount the array without losing any data.

Here is my original script. There are parts of it which I obviously do not want to reexecute as they will delete the data.

```
sudo sgdisk -p /dev/sdb
sudo sgdisk -p /dev/sdd
sudo sgdisk -p /dev/sde

# DELETE ALL DATA 
#sudo sgdisk --clear /dev/sdb
#sudo sgdisk --clear /dev/sdd
#sudo sgdisk --clear /dev/sde

sudo sgdisk -n 1:2048:3907028991 /dev/sdb -c 1:"R1b"
sudo sgdisk -n 1:2048:3907028991 /dev/sdd -c 1:"R2d"
sudo sgdisk -n 1:2048:3907028991 /dev/sde -c 1:"R3e"

#sudo mkfs.ext4 -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 
#sudo mkfs.ext4 -t ext4 /dev/sdd1 
#sudo mkfs.ext4 -t ext4 /dev/sde1 

#https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup
#chunk size = 128kB (set by mdadm cmd, see chunk size advise above)
#block size = 4kB (recommended for large files, and most of time)
#stride = chunk / block = 128kB / 4k = 32
#stripe-width = stride * ( (n disks in raid5) - 1 ) = 32 * ( (3) - 1 ) = 32 * 2 = 64

sudo mkfs.ext4 -v -m .1 -b 4096 -E stride=32,stripe-width=64 /dev/sdb1 
sudo mkfs.ext4 -v -m .1 -b 4096 -E stride=32,stripe-width=64 /dev/sdd1 
sudo mkfs.ext4 -v -m .1 -b 4096 -E stride=32,stripe-width=64 /dev/sde1 


# make sure you have RAID module in the linux kernel
sudo modprobe raid456
cat /proc/mdstat

# Create RAID 5
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=3  /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1
sudo mdadm --detail --scan 
sudo mdadm --query --detail /dev/md0
sudo mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf

cat /proc/mdstat

# Start RAID
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan 
sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0

# Stop RAID
sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md0

# Format the RAID
sudo mkfs.ext4 -v -m .1 -b 4096 -E stride=32,stripe-width=64 /dev/md0 

# Mount the RAID (dont forget to modify fstab)
sudo mkdir /media/raid
sudo chown username:username /media/raid
sudo mount /dev/md0 /media/raid
echo "/dev/md0    /media/raid       ext4  defaults     1  2" >> /etc/fstab

# Stop Rebuild
sudo /usr/share/mdadm/checkarray -xa
# Reconfigure initramfs
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

In short I need help picking a subset of these commands (or maybe there is something easier I can do). My best guess is something like this: Is it as simple as?:

```
# Create RAID 5
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=3  /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1
# Mount the RAID (dont forget to modify fstab)
sudo mkdir /media/raid
sudo chown username:username /media/raid
sudo mount /dev/md0 /media/raid
echo "/dev/md0    /media/raid       ext4  defaults     1  2" >> /etc/fstab
```

or will that not work / kill my data?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=3  /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1
```

If you do this your raid is dead as a completely new superblock is written. Unfortunately you cannot use "--build" on level 5.

You should check what exactly happens when the raid is trying to be started, just use

```
mdadm --assamble --scan
```

Under normal circumstances, "mdadm --assmeble --scan" automatically assembles your raidset and create the device to mount (usually /dev/md0).

If this step fails, the cause is hard to tell from what you describe. The output of following commands could help:

mdadm --examine --scan
blkid
cat /proc/mdstat